# How to send .xml file with correct name using as2?

Tags: python, xml, edi

I have a partner with whom we exchange .edi messages using the as2 protocol.

Now we need to switch to messaging in the .xml format. Moreover, my partner wants the files to have the correct names.

I use my own library (based on pyas2lib). Judging by the information I found on the internet, I need to change the message headers. I changed "Content-Disposition" to "attachment; filename=my_file.xml ", added the parameter "name" = my_file.xml, changed the type to "application/xml".
But all to no avail - the file content is displayed correctly, but its name looks like a random set of characters.

Is there any way I can send a file with the correct name? If so, how do I do it? Should the partner specify any settings for themselves?

I will be glad of any help on this issue and will try to answer any questions that arise.

Comment: AS2 is encrypted and is a MIME attachment in the body of the HTTP message.  MIME starts with two dashes on a new line in the body.  See the following links.  Ask if you need more info : https://www.seeburger.com/resources/good-to-know/what-is-as2 https://aayutechnologies.com/docs/as2/mime-smime-and-as2/  https://portx.io/what-is-as2/

Comment: First make sure you are getting a 200 OK as a response.  The XML is a MIME attachment so you need to change the Content-Type of the attachment and not the Content-Type of the Request/Response.  This link give more info on MIME : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)

Comment: @jdweng ty for your cooment! I get not only the 200 OK status, but also the correct MDN (at least it doesn't differ from what I get when I send message with .edi file). I repeat that, partner see correct file content, but not its name.

Comment: AS2 is encrypted.   Are you encrypting the Filename?  Is the filename being decrypted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it often happens, it turned out to be my inattention. The name of the file being transferred and the type of content are controlled by the `build()` method of the Message class in pyas2lib.

Before that, I passed these values **after building** the message, which led to incorrect operation.